# Fix .android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist. error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently changed the location of .android folder to another drive in my computer. But after that when i run any project it shows me this error

File 'G:\Freelance_Project_Files\Agora_RTM_SDK_for_Android_v1_2_2\Agora_RTM_SDK_for_Android\samples\Agora_RTM_Tutorial_Android\app\D:.android.android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

change the location of your key-store in the app build gradle in this section and then clean and rebuild the project

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
             storeFile file('your key-store path')
             storePassword '******'
             keyAlias = 'key_store_alias'
             keyPassword '******'

        }
    }
```